# How to disable input after x amount of clicks in vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an input button which generates a new form every everytime you click it but I'm struggling to disable it after 10 clicks as I don't want the user to be able to create an infinite amount of forms. Here it is:

```js
var room = 1;
function add_fields() {
  room++;
  var objTo = document.getElementById("room_fileds");
  var divtest = document.createElement("div");
  divtest.innerHTML =
    '<div class="control-group">' +
    '<label class="control-label">Company</label>' +
    '<div class="controls">' +
    '<input class="input-border collection-input "id="company" name="company' +
    room +
    ' "type="text" placeholder="Company">' +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>" 

  objTo.appendChild(divtest);
}
```

```html
<div id="room_fileds">
  <div class='label'>Drop off address:</div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="more_fields" class="btn mt-3 mb-2" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" />
```

Here's what I tried:

```
var room = 1;
function add_fields() {
 if(room < 11){
   room++
 }
  var objTo = document.getElementById("room_fileds");
  var divtest = document.createElement("div");
  divtest.innerHTML =
    '<div class="control-group">' +
    '<label class="control-label">Company</label>' +
    '<div class="controls">' +
    '<input class="input-border collection-input "id="company" name="company' +
    room +
    ' "type="text" placeholder="Company">' +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>" 

  objTo.appendChild(divtest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the if statement around the whole function and it should work as you expect.

```
var room = 1
function add_fields() {
  if (room < 11) {
    room++

    var objTo = document.getElementById("room_fileds")
    var divtest = document.createElement("div")
    divtest.innerHTML =
      '<div class="control-group">' +
      '<label class="control-label">Company</label>' +
      '<div class="controls">' +
      '<input class="input-border collection-input "id="company" name="company' +
      room +
      ' "type="text" placeholder="Company">' +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>"

    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple

Answer (score 1):

Remove or disable button for make this action?:

```
var room = 1;
function add_fields() {
    if(room < 11) {
        room++

        var objTo = document.getElementById("room_fileds");
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.innerHTML =
        '<div class="control-group">' +
        '<label class="control-label">Company</label>' +
        '<div class="controls">' +
        '<input class="input-border collection-input "id="company" name="company' +
        room +
        ' "type="text" placeholder="Company">' +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" 

        objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('more_fields').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        //or
        document.getElementById('more_fields').remove();
    }
}
```

or show alert - your choose